# Make sure, pipelines run sequential in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd, gitlab-ce

of course I am aware, that single jobs run in sequence FIFO if these jobs are pointing to a single runner, so they have to wait.

That is fine.

For a test environment, where we can only deploy & test one version at a time, we need not only single jobs to be queryed, but whole pipelines.

To be clear: If we have `Job_Deploy` & `Job_Test` which are Part of a Pipeline `Pipeline`, we need to wait for the whole pipeline to be done.

By now we have the scenario, that the sequence can possible not be in order:

`Job_Deploy1`, `Job_Deploy2`, `Job_Test2`, `Job_Test1` may be the case.

But we need it strict FIFO

`Pipeline1(Job_Deploy1, Job_Test1)`, `Pipeline(Job_Deploy2, Job_Test2)`

How can we achieve this?

Why do we seem to be alone with this requirement? Do we have any wrong perceptions here? Is it best practice? If not: why?

Best regards

Comment: can you show your gitlab-ci.yaml code?

Answer (score 2):

Try `Edit an existing resource group` with `process_mode oldest_first`

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/resource_groups.html#edit-an-existing-resource-group

Comment: That sounds interesting

Answer (score -1):

It seems like i misread the question and my initial answer is not applicable, i leave it at the end.

---

Right answer:

> Use resource_group to create a resource group that ensures a job is mutually exclusive across different pipelines for the same project.

There are are so called `resource_groups` which you can use to force a certain order. and which ensures that jobs only run after each other even if they are in separate pipelines.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#resource_group

---

Wrong answer:

What you are looking for is the `needs` directive.

It offers you the possibility to express job dependencies within your ci file.

Something like

```yaml
deploy1:
  script: echo "deploy 1"

test1:
  script: echo "test 1"
  needs:
    - deploy1
```

This means that `test1` even if it is in the same stage, will not start as long as `deploy1` has finished. Furthermore, you could also add `needs: []` to `deploy1` to start it immediately even if it is in a later stage. `needs` is powerful and allows you to work outside the stage boundaries.

Take a look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. Sorry for answering late. It seems not to be the solution. The thing is: It solves, that PipeA.JobX never runs parallel to PipeB.JobX, that is right.

But it does not guarantee: That PipeB.JobX waits for PipeA to finish with JobX, than JobY and than JobZ, doen't it?

Comment: @ChrisPillen I would say the same thing. Did you have the answer?

Comment: @BenoitGalati Unfortunately, that was not the point. Not the order inside a pipeline is the problem, but the order of pipelines. It has to be save, that only `Pipeline1(Job_Deploy1, Job_Test1), Pipeline(Job_Deploy2, Job_Test2)` can happen, not `Job_Deploy1, Job_Deploy2, Job_Test2, Job_Test1`